# Can files be created with permissions set on the command line?

Tags: shell, permissions, files

When creating directories, `mkdir -m <mode> <dir>` provides for creating one or more directories with the given mode/permissions set (atomically).

Is there an equivalent for creating files, on the command line?

Something akin to:

```
open("file", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, 0777);
```

Is using `touch` followed by a `chmod` my only option here?

---

**Edit:** After trying out teppic's suggestion to use `install`, I ran it through `strace` to see how close to atomic it was. The answer is, not very:

```
$ strace install -m 777 /dev/null newfile
...
open("newfile", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0666) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0666, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
...
fchmod(4, 0600)                         = 0
close(4)                                = 0
...
chmod("newfile", 0777)                  = 0
...
```

Still, it's a single shell command and one I didn't know before.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You could use the `install` command with a dummy file, e.g.

```
install -b -m 755 /dev/null newfile
```

The `-b` option backs up `newfile` if it already exists. You can use this command to set the owner as well.

On Linux it's usually part of GNU [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/install-invocation.html) or [BusyBox](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#install), but it's also available on systems derived from 4.2BSD, e.g. [FreeBSD](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=install&sektion=1), [NetBSD](https://man.netbsd.org/install.1) or [OpenBSD](https://man.openbsd.org/install.1).

Comment: It's a useful little command. As its name suggests it's really designed for installing software compiled from source code, to save having to use chmod, chown, and so forth all the time.

Comment: If only it took stdin! OK, /proc/self/fd/0 will do for my purpose.

Comment: Note that mode 755 is the default permissions of files created with `install`, so `-m 755` is not needed.

Comment: @Kusalananda It's obviously just an example of how to set a mode, since that was the question, not how to set 755.

Comment: @proski another option is a process substitution; `install -b -m 755 <(echo contents) newfile` worked for me.

Comment: `install` does not atomically create files with the given permissions. It calls `fchmod()` separately. An unauthorised user may open the file between the creation and the permissions change, thus it possible to read contents later that they are not allowed to read (e.g. for a private key file). Thus `install` should not be used if file permission security is important. (This was edited into the question, but I think it's good to state it under this answer since it's currently marked accepted despite not fulfilling the requested "atomic" requirement.)

Answer (score 29):

`touch` always creates the file if it doesn't exist, always follows symbolic links, and always makes the file non-executable. You can decide the read and write bits through the [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask).

```
(umask 077; touch file)  # creates a 600 (rw-------) file
(umask 002; touch file)  # creates a 664 (rw-rw-r--) file
```

“Safe” atomic file creation (in particular, with `O_NOFOLLOW`) is not possible with traditional shell tools. You can use `sysopen` in perl. If you have the BSD-inspired `mktemp` utility, it creates a file atomically with `O_NOFOLLOW`; you'll have to to call `chmod` afterwards if the default mode of 600 is not the right one.

Comment: I was in the process of writing out a more detailed explanation, but the wikipedia articles covers everything just fine.

Comment: If only `touch` had the option of creating executable files, that's really what I'm after. Then `umask` could be used to tailor the details. Sadly there is no way with `umask` and `touch` to create executables.

Comment: @quornian You can't create a non-empty file atomically anyway. What's the point of creating an empty executable file atomically? Use `touch` followed by `chmod +x`.

Comment: You can create non-empty, executables files atomically with... ln or mv. You can always create the file with the right content and permissions in a directory created with umask 077 and move it or ln it afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Building on @teppic's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47182/1174), if you want to create the file with content and mode at the same time (bash):

```bash
install -m 755 <(echo commands go here) newscript
```

`<()` places the output into a temporary file, see [Process-Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)

Comment: When you downvote could you let me know why? afaik this works just fine

Answer (score 1):

With zsh's `sysopen` builtin (enabled with `zmodload zsh/system`) you can specify the mode with `-m`, still subject to `umask`, but you can set it to 0:

```
zmodload zsh/system
(umask 0 && sysopen -u fd -m 777 -o excl file)
```

Should be atomic. `strace` shows:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "file", O_RDONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_NOCTTY, 0777) = 3
```

`-o excl` is for it to fail with a *"file exists"" error when the file already existed, so you can do `(...) || chmod 777 file` for instance. Replace with `-o creat` to just open it (still in read-only with `-r`) when it already existed. In any case, the fd is  closed as soon as the subshell exists.

You can also set the uid and gid at the same time atomically if you're superuser and set the `EGID` and `EUID` variables (in that order) beforehand:

```
(umask 0 && EGID=456 EUID=123 && sysopen -u fd -m 777 -o excl file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can really do this from just standard tools, but if you have access to a python interpreter, you can do something like:

```
python3 -c 'import os, sys, shutil; shutil.copyfileobj(sys.stdin, open("filename.txt", "w", opener=lambda name, flag: os.open(name, flag, mode=0o631)))' <<< "file_content"
```

Expanded, the python script basically does:

```
import os, sys, shutil
file_opener = lambda name, flag: os.open(name, flag, mode=0o631)
dest = open("filename.txt", "w", opener=file_opener)
shutil.copyfileobj(sys.stdin, dest)
```

There's probably something similar in other scripting language interpreter's toolkit.

Output of `strace`:

```
$ strace python3 -c 'import os, sys, shutil; shutil.copyfileobj(sys.stdin, open("filename.txt", "w", opener=lambda name, flag: os.open(name, flag, mode=0o631)))' <<< "file_content"
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "filename.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_CLOEXEC, 0631) = 3
ioctl(3, FIOCLEX)                       = 0
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0631, st_size=0, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffe4fce65e0)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffe4fce6430)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
brk(0x55c88d356000)                     = 0x55c88d356000
read(0, "file_content\n", 65536)        = 13
brk(0x55c88d346000)                     = 0x55c88d346000
read(0, "", 65523)                      = 0
read(0, "", 65536)                      = 0
write(3, "file_content\n", 13)          = 13
...
```

---

Alternatively, if the only reason you care about atomicity is just to prevent the file content being read from a hostile process running as other users, and not necessarily the use of atomicity of `open(..., mode)` itself, you can just set the umask to 777 in a subprocess so that the file is first created to deny permission to everyone:

```
$ (umask 777; <<< "file_content" > filename.txt)
$ ls -lah filename.txt
---------- 1 lieryan lieryan 13 Sep  8 15:58 filename.txt
```

then set the file permission with the right value right afterwards:

```
$ chmod 631 filename.txt
```

Or, putting it all together:

```
$ (umask 777; <<< "file_content" > filename.txt; chmod 631 filename.txt)
```

This is still susceptible to race condition attacks from other processes running as the same user, but if you have to worry about that, you're probably worrying about the wrong thing.

Answer (score -1):

I have a bash script in my home directory `/home/anthony/touchmod.sh` containing:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch "$2"
chmod "$1" "$2"
```

So if I need to create `readme.txt` with 644 permissions I can type:

```
~/touchmod.sh 644 readme.txt
```

Comment: You likely did not understand the question. This is exactly what the questioner tries to avoid.