# Why does OS X `install` errors on redirected input when the same version of `install` on linux works fine?

Tags: shell, files, osx, executable, process-substitution

I would like to use `install` command in order to create a new executable file with pre-populated content (e.g. with single `pwd` command in it).

So I've extended [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47182/21471) example which creates a new empty executable file:

```
install -b -m 755 /dev/null newfile
```

into this one:

```
install -m755 <(echo pwd) newfile
```

or:

```
echo pwd | install -m755 /dev/stdin newfile
```

Where I expect to create a new `newfile` executable file to be created with content `pwd` inside.

It works on Linux, however on OS X it fails with the following error:

- BSD `install` (`/usr/bin/install`)

  > install: `/dev/fd/63`: Inappropriate file type or format
- GNU `install` (`/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/install`)

  > install: skipping file `/dev/fd/63`, as it was replaced while being copied

Why this doesn't work on Unix, but it works on Linux? I'm missing anything? Is there any way to bypass the above warning by using different syntax (**without** creating a file in separate commands and using `chmod` after that)?

---

On both environments (Linux & OS X) I've the same version of `install`:

```
$ install --version
install (GNU coreutils) 8.23
```

Comment: I just tried the syntax `install -m755 <(echo pwd) newfile` on a `centOS 7` machine, and it worked correctly. using the syntax `install -m755 <(echo pwd)> newfile` produced the error you are receiving though. I realize this doesn't implicitly help you, but it does show that your premise is sound at least. It *should* be working

Comment: May be better to ask on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @MarkPlotnick At golf they don't like shell challenges. I've simplified question, as Gravy hint helped me to point, that it actually suppose to work, but it isn't as expected. So it actually isn't challenge, but a specific command syntax question.

Comment: OK, I see the edited question no longer has puzzle-like constraints.

Comment: If you use `zsh`, you may try the `=(cmd)` syntax instead of `<(cmd)`.  From the man: "If  `=(...)` is used instead of `<(...)`, then the file passed as an argument will be the name of a temporary file containing the
       output of the list process.  This may be used instead of the `<` form for a program that expects to `lseek` (see `lseek(2)`) on the
       input file."  Otherwise `mkfifo` is your best bet.

Comment: @kenorb I don't know what version of OS X you're using, but certainly on mine (10.11.3, El Capitan), `install` is part of the BSD suite, not GNU. Unless you're using homebrew to install custom versions of cmds, anything you use will be the BSD version and therefore differ in functionality from those of GNU Linux.

Comment: @py4on You're correct. I've different error with BSD install. I've updated with clarification.

Comment: @kenorb I'm don't know if you've come across this in you're own research into the problem, but your error message seems to have been widespread amongst Cygwin users, most often using `cp`. This is just one example: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.os.cygwin/129935

Comment: @py4on I've found by accident when experimenting with creation of executable file with content which I wanted to achieve in one go. So it was working on Linux VM, but when tested locally on OS X, to my surprise it failed.

Comment: @kenorb Ok, looks like this is considered a kernel bug (reported on RedHat https://goo.gl/Bc2xx2 and Samba https://goo.gl/tf4IdG bugzillas) which was patched in kernel 2.6.36.

Comment: @py4on How this is related to OS X kernel? This happens on Mac for both `install` versions.

Comment: Unless they share the same bug with some similar code.

Comment: It's impossible to have same versions! OS X is using BSD version of Install, while Linux Distros are using GNU coreutils! The only thing is common, is the name of it, even options provide slight different jobs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BSD install found on OpenBSD systems has this piece of code in it (from `src/usr.bin/xinstall/xinstall.c`):

```
if (!S_ISREG(to_sb.st_mode))
    errc(1, EFTYPE, "%s", to_name);
```

This emits the error

```
install: /dev/fd/4: Inappropriate file type or format
```

when it's discovered that `/dev/df/4` is not a regular file. (There's a separate earlier check for `/dev/null`)

That was fairly straight forward.

GNU `install` has this code (`src/install.c` in `coreutils`):

```
  /* Allow installing from non-regular files like /dev/null.
     Charles Karney reported that some Sun version of install allows that
     and that sendmail's installation process relies on the behavior.
     However, since !x->recursive, the call to "copy" will fail if FROM
     is a directory.  */

  return copy (from, to, false, x, &copy_into_self, NULL);
```

The code emitting the error comes from `src/copy.c`:

```
  source_desc = open (src_name,
                      (O_RDONLY | O_BINARY
                       | (x->dereference == DEREF_NEVER ? O_NOFOLLOW : 0)));
```

(a few lines omitted)

```
  if (fstat (source_desc, &src_open_sb) != 0)
    {
      error (0, errno, _("cannot fstat %s"), quoteaf (src_name));
      return_val = false;
      goto close_src_desc;
    }

  /* Compare the source dev/ino from the open file to the incoming,
     saved ones obtained via a previous call to stat.  */
  if (! SAME_INODE (*src_sb, src_open_sb))
    {
      error (0, 0,
             _("skipping file %s, as it was replaced while being copied"),
             quoteaf (src_name));
```

This is in `copy_reg()` which copies a regular file. The `SAME_INODE` macro evaluates to false because the inodes differ in the two `stat` structs `*src_sb` and `src_open_sb`.  The `*src_sb` comes from a `stat()` or `lstat()` call on the source file name and `src_open_sb` from `fstat()` as seen above, on a newly open descriptor.

I can kinda see why opening a new file descriptor and comparing its inode to that of the file descriptor given by the shell (`/dev/fd/4` in my case) will fail, but I can't put it into definite words unfortunately.