# Is it possible to make files executable by owner by default?

Tags: files, permissions, umask

Since the file base permissions for umask are 666, is it possible to make a file have 750 permissions when created?

Comment: Of possible interest: [How to set default file permissions for all folders/files in a directory?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory).

Comment: It depends. What is creating the file?

Comment: Please check this.
[http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47178/can-files-be-created-with-permissions-set-on-the-command-line](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47178/can-files-be-created-with-permissions-set-on-the-command-line)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, no. Virtually every program calls `open()` (or `creat()` for that matter) with mode `0666`, so whatever `umask` you apply, you'll never get `0750`. Even the linker, which creates executables, opens output files with mode `0666` and `chmod` them later:

```
strace -f -e file gcc bla.c 2>&1 | fgrep a.out 
...
[pid 14096] open("a.out", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
...
[pid 14096] chmod("a.out", 0755)        = 0
```

If you want different behavior, you need to write your own tools or wrappers around existing tools that perform the intended mode change.